# Select every text node in a HTML document except script nodes with XPath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am currently writing a web crawler with Scrapy, and I would like to fetch all the text displayed on the screen of every HTML document with a single XPath query.

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Main title</h1>
    <div>
      <script>var grandson;</script>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>var child;</script>
</body>
```

As you can see, there are some `script` tags that I want to filter when getting the text inside the `body` tag

Here is my first XPath query and its result:

`XPath: /body/*//text()`
`Result: Main title / var grandson; / Paragraph / var child;`

This is not good because it also fetches the text inside the `script` tag.

Here is my second try:

`XPath: /body/*[not(self::script)]//text()`
`Result: Main title / var grandson; / Paragraph`

Here, the last `script` tag (which is `body`'s child) is filtered, but the inner `script` is not.

How would you filter all the `script` tags ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
//*[not(self::script)]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

This xPath does what you want.

```
.//text()[not(parent::script)]
```

So we have looking what is parent of text.

More interesting sample. I can use it for each element which contains **html code**.

```
.//text()[not(ancestor::script|ancestor::style|ancestor::noscript)]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I use xpath axes. Text is node and I check parent for this node. If it isn't script I get this text.